# Automatic flowchart generation from paper structure

Tags: flow-charts

In a long paper one often has a quite convoluted web of implications between lemmas theorems corollaries etc.

Has anyone written code that automatically generates a flowchart displaying the logical dependencies between these?

Comment: while not having done any of that i can only recommend maybe looking at the problem from a different angle; since programs in <WHATEVERLANGUAGE> have the same property there are tools like doxygen. and in doxygens output you can include graphs that show dependencies between code modules classes files and what not (generated by graphviz (or similar dont quote me on the name)) so i would try finding a doxygen configuration that works with latex so you can sort of do that thing. but thats only my first take. dont put all your hopes on it.

Comment: You might look at DOT:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29  There are tools that let you create LaTeX friendly-graphics from DOT source files.

Comment: For the document structure you can convert it to markdown and then to a mind map: http://pzhao.org/pkg/mindr/index.html